# Link a .a library with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I want to link my .a library with CMake as I am used to with :
 `cc main.c -L/usr/lib64 -lmlx -L/usr/lib64/X11 -lXext -lX11`
I use Clion from JetBRAINS.

I tried in my CMake :

```
target_link_libraries(fdf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a)
target_link_libraries(fdf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.a)
```

Comment: I tried :                                                                                       target_link_libraries(fdf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a)
target_link_libraries(fdf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.a)

Comment: show the output of `make VERBOSE=ON`. More information is required...

Comment: What is `fdf` by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your

```
target_link_libraries(fdf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a)
target_link_libraries(fdf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.a)
```

as:

```
target_link_libraries(fdf)
link_directories("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
target_link_libraries(X11)
target_link_libraries(Xext)
```

As you mentioned in your answer, it might be that you have to shuffle the order of the last 2 lines
and so on.